# Display all the contents retrieved from a json response

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have endpoints that consume JSON responses. I can the number of the length in the JSON endpoint calling the length attribute of the array. This is the snippet of code that I am using to consume the JSON response:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
Data[] response = restTemplate.getForObject("url",  Data[].class);

Integer response2 = response.length;

for(int i=0; i < response.length; i++)
{
    //retrieve all the contents of the json response here
}
```

**EDITTED:**

IT IS IN THIS FORMAT

```
[{"id":1,"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi",
"state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi","state_data":"hi"},
```

My challenge is how can I retrieve all the contents in the JSON array as fields. Thanks in assistance received.

Answer (score 0):

Errr, judging by the amount of code presented you would want to iterate over the array like so:

```
for(int i=0; i < response.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println(response[i]) // prints the toString of a Data object. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on what is in the JSON responses, here is an example.

If this is the response that you get:

```
{"result": [ {"key":"value1"}, {"key":"value2"} ] }
```

The following code will print out value1, value2.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());

JSONArray result = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

for(int n = 0; n < result.length(); n++) {
    JSONObject item = result.getJSONObject(n);
    System.out.println(item.getString("key"));
}
```

Comment: jsonobject is not a class

Comment: @parker Can you post the JSON responses that you are trying to parse? The JSONObject jsonObj reference in my code snippet above is the JSON object created from the JSON response, knowing the JSON responses that you receive will clarify how to parse it (to retrieve the key-value pair).

Comment: @parker Can you post the JSON response (the input that you are trying to parse)?

Comment: @parker That does not look like a valid json object (the key "state_data" are duplicates in the same json object).